# Check Column By another Column and Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
MasterStock table
CID | StockAvailable |
1   | 15              |
2   | 5               |

MasterPackage table
PID | CID   | StockPackage |
1   | 1     | 20           |
1   | 2     | 2            |
```

I want to create a stored procedure, to check the availibility stock on the masterstock table based on stockpackage on the masterpackage table.

and i want to achieved it, **on single query.**

MasterPackage table by PID will insert auto to Trans Table.

```
Trans table
TID | PID | CID   | StockIssue |
```

> if StockAvailable >= StockPackage, INSERT status True
>
> if StockAvailable < StockPackage, INSERT status False

*StockPackage as Stock Issue*

please help.

Comment: the condition seems like contradict with the sample result shown

Comment: I already delete the record on the Trans Table. I just want to show the fields on that table.

Comment: What is the expected result for the sample data given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an `INNER JOIN` on CID

```
INSERT INTO Trans (PID, SID, StockIssue)
SELECT p.PID, p.SID, p.StockPackage AS StockIssue 
FROM   MasterPackage AS p
       INNER JOIN MasterStock AS s
       ON s.CID = p.CID
WHERE  s.StockAvailable >= p.StockPackage
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need the stored procedure in here as you can do it in one simple query, but here is what you've requested :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE StockAvailability
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Trans(PID, CID, StockIssue) 
SELECT 
    MP.PID, 
    MP.CID,
    CASE 
        WHEN MS.StockAvailable >= MP.StockPackage THEN 'True'
        WHEN MS.StockAvailable < MP.StockPackage  THEN 'False'
    END AS StockIssue 
FROM MasterPackage MP
LEFT JOIN MasterStock MS ON MS.CID = MP.PID

END
```

If `StockIssue` is `BIT` datatype, then replace `'True'` with `1` and `'False'` with `0`.

If you're going to use it regularly with other tables or columns, then you can define a scalar function to compare the values between two columns, which is a solution for general purpose that will gives more flexibility (something will make your life easier).

Something like :

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckAvailability
(
    @MasterStock INT,
    @StockPackage INT 

)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE
        @Result VARCHAR(50)

SET 
    @Result = 
    CASE 
        WHEN @MasterStock >= @StockPackage THEN 'True'
        WHEN @MasterStock <  @StockPackage THEN 'False'
    END 

    RETURN @Result

END
```

And then call it :

```
SELECT 
    MP.PID, 
    MP.CID,
    dbo.CheckAvailability(MS.StockAvailable, MP.StockPackage) AS StockIssue 
FROM MasterPackage MP
LEFT JOIN MasterStock MS ON MS.CID = MP.PID
```

You can use it in anywhere you want.